# MongoDB C# Drivier - Deserializing HybridDictionary

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

We're currently looking to implement a sort of persistent cache utilizing MongoDB as the repository. We're working with a legacy code base which contains classes  that utilize HybridDictionary, a .net specialized collection.

A sample class structure that we're using is as follows:

```
public class Section
{
    HybridDictionary _SubSections = new HybridDictionary(true);

    public Guid SectionID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public HybridDictionary SubSections {get { return this._SubSections; }}
}
```

The `SubSections` property, in this instance, contains additional `Section` type items. Basically a parent, then it's children. It's children can additional children, etc.

When we use the Mongo Driver to FindAndModify one of these documents, we're running a Query which expects a `MongoCacheItem`. A `MongoCacheItem`contains an `Object` property which is, in this instance, a type of `Section`.

```
public class MongoCacheItem
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; } // This is a `Section`
}

CacheContext.Cache.FindAndModify(new FindAndModifyArgs
{
    Query = Query<MongoCacheItem>.EQ(x => x.Key, key),
    Update = Update.Replace(cacheItem),
    Upsert = true
});
```

When we run the above logic, the first `Section` is serialized correctly. So we get a document in Mongo that contains properties `sectionid` and `name`, but no `SubSections`.

After digging through the serialization documentation we found that we could decorate the `SubSections` property with `[BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)]`, so now we have:

```
public class Section
{
    HybridDictionary _SubSections = new HybridDictionary(true);

    public Guid SectionID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)]
    public HybridDictionary SubSections {get { return this._SubSections; }}
}
```

Again, running the FindAndModfiy, we now get a a document which contains the fully serialized object WITH the `SubSections` serialized as an array of documents with all the children. This works as expected.

However, when we retrieve the document from Mongo using FindOne, the Value is being returned with only the base `Section` deserialized. The `SubSections` property is just an empty collection.

I was wondering if anyone has encountered this issue before or if you have any suggestions for a possible solution to the deserialization problem. One possible solution that we've been toying with is building a custom serializer and registering it with Mongo for HybridDictionary types. However, since the cache item `value` is just a plain old `object`, we could run into additional types that are unable to be serialized/deserialized and therefore might need to build a bunch of different serializers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB driver need at least a **private set** for a property

```
[BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)]
public HybridDictionary SubSections 
{ 
    get { return this._SubSections; } 
    private set { this._SubSections = value; } 
}
```